# Set an array value to another arrays value

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays, and I am trying to copy the array values from one to the other, but not all of them. Here is the code that I have. I am getting an error on the line with `finalplace[y] = place[y];`. I have another array called `place`, which is the longer array. I do not want to make an exact copy of the place array. I just want to get the first array values where their placement is less than `count`. Any ideas?

```
int [] finalplace = new int [count];
for (int y = 0; y <= count; y = y + 1) {
    finalplace[y] = place[y];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indices of your new array range up to, but not including, `count`. So you should do the same with your `for` loop.

Note that [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) will let you copy part of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use the utility class

```
java.util.Arrays
```

there are a bunch of copy methods. For instance [copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29) or [copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **[System.arraycopy()](http://www.javadb.com/how-to-copy-an-array)**

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = new int[5];

System.arraycopy( a, 0, b, 0, a.length );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.copyOf method instead of taking burden of copying each element.